# How to delete columns?

Tags: unix, shell, text

I have generated the following text file below:

```
fe120b99164f151b28bf86afa6389b22 -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey 186 2010-03-14 19:26 Descript.txt
41705ea936cfc653f273b5454c1cdde6 -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey  30 2010-03-14 20:29 listof.txt
0e25cca3222d32fff43563465af03340 -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey  28 2010-03-14 23:35 sedexample.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test1.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test2.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test3.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test4.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test5.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test6.txt
f5c7f1856249d0526be10df5bd5b895a -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey  26 2010-03-13 14:13 testingfile.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e -rw-r--r-- 1 joey joey   0 2010-03-15 00:28 uniquelist.txt
```

Basically I would like to get rid of the access, amount column, user and group columns.  In other words, I want rid of columns 3,4,5.  I have tried using cut to keep the columns that I do want and having " " as my delimiter however because of the file size figures, it messes up using "space" as a delimiter.  Any advice would be much appreciated!  Oh just to add, I would like to save the output as another text file.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how does your `cut` command look like?

```
$ cut -d" " -f1,6- file
fe120b99164f151b28bf86afa6389b22 186 2010-03-14 19:26 Descript.txt
41705ea936cfc653f273b5454c1cdde6  30 2010-03-14 20:29 listof.txt
0e25cca3222d32fff43563465af03340  28 2010-03-14 23:35 sedexample.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test1.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test2.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test3.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test4.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test5.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   0 2010-02-16 15:11 test6.txt
f5c7f1856249d0526be10df5bd5b895a  26 2010-03-13 14:13 testingfile.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e   0 2010-03-15 00:28 uniquelist.txt
```

redirect to new file as needed.

Or awk

```
$ awk '{$2=$3=$4=$5="";gsub(/ +/," ")}1' file
fe120b99164f151b28bf86afa6389b22 186 2010-03-14 19:26 Descript.txt
41705ea936cfc653f273b5454c1cdde6 30 2010-03-14 20:29 listof.txt
0e25cca3222d32fff43563465af03340 28 2010-03-14 23:35 sedexample.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 0 2010-02-16 15:11 test1.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 0 2010-02-16 15:11 test2.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 0 2010-02-16 15:11 test3.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 0 2010-02-16 15:11 test4.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 0 2010-02-16 15:11 test5.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 0 2010-02-16 15:11 test6.txt
f5c7f1856249d0526be10df5bd5b895a 26 2010-03-13 14:13 testingfile.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 0 2010-03-15 00:28 uniquelist.txt
```

Comment: My original cut command was like this:

more indexfile.txt | cut -d " " -f 1,6,7,8,9  >goodindex.txt

Comment: @Joey jie: In case it is not clear why your initial *cut* sometimes dropped the time and/or filename: The extra padding spaces in the size(?) column created extra, empty fields internally in *cut*. This caused your field enumeration to be too short in some cases. If you used `-f1,6,7,8,9,10,11` it would have worked, but obviously `-f1,6-` is more succinct and flexible. You would need a different solution if you wanted to cut out fields that were beyond the first space-padded column. Maybe `cut -c` if all the columns (before and including the columns you want to cut) have fixed widths.

Answer (score 4):

Easily done as a shell pipe.

```
cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=3-5 --complement
```

If you really need to do this in C, you could run that command in a subprocess via `popen`.

If you had mixed space and tab delimiters, you would need to convert one to the other as `cut` does not like multiple delimiters. Do this with `tr` or `col -x`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to do this in C? This would be easier to do in a scripting language like perl, or even awk.

```
awk '{print $1 $6 $7 $8 $9}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Pipe it through `awk '{print $1 $6 $7 $8 $9;}'`?

Comment: this answer compresses all the spaces out, it's just one big long "word"

Answer (score 0):

I smell homework, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt.

Cut will work, but you need to merge one or more spaces into just one first:

```
sed "s/ \+/ /g" input_file | cut -d' ' -f-2,6-
```

To save the output of any command to a file, it's `command > file`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using awk '{print $1 $6 $7 $8 $9}' file.txt however it gives me the following output:

fe120b99164f151b28bf86afa6389b221862010-03-1419:26Descriptions.txt
41705ea936cfc653f273b5454c1cdde6302010-03-1420:29listofnumbers.txt
0e25cca3222d32fff43563465af03340282010-03-1423:35sedexample.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e02010-02-1615:11test1.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e02010-02-1615:11test2.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e02010-02-1615:11test3.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e02010-02-1615:11test4.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e02010-02-1615:11test5.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e02010-02-1615:11test6.txt
f5c7f1856249d0526be10df5bd5b895a262010-03-1314:13testingfile.txt
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e02010-03-1500:28uniquelist.txt

All the columns have become joined into one which is not ideal for me as I will be using uniq one this at some point.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -lane'$, = " "; print @F[0,5..$#F]' input.txt
```

NOTE: As well as [the `cut` version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444853/how-to-delete-columns/2444916#2444916) it replaces two or more spaces in the input by a single space e.g., it can broke filenames in the input.

Answer (score -1):

Try to open  them in excel with space as delimiter, delete it there. See if it works.